# I want to replace text in my WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, hook-woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages, woocommerce-subscriptions

Kindly look at this this here you can see here is mentioned (8 left) i want to replace (left with places left) means in simple i want to show 8 places left…

https://digitalrise.website/product/kayak-lisbon/?date=2022-11-07

Here is link below

Answer (score 0):

you can try this-

```
<div class="text-align: left">
<span>8 Left</span>
</div>
```

Please try this code, if you still facing issue just lemme know, i will help you more.

Thanks

Comment: The main problem is that in finding class.. I find in different location in theme but I'm unable to find class

Comment: okay then pass div id and add custom code in edit css which is available in the wordpress

Comment: .spaces-left:after {
visibility: visible;
content: " places";
}   Where .spaces-left is class assigned by plugin... But i want to write places left not left places

Comment: Hey @CodistanPro i think you don't know basic theme editing of wordpress.. Where just need to pass css with classname and edit that class in the frontend of page.. Because above code doesn't need any special plugin

Comment: Can you help me how to do that? It's DIVI theme?!

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML code for that page, find the following code:

`<small class="spaces-left">8 left</small>`

It is contained inside this class: `<div class="form-field form-field-wide">`

Change the part of that HTML that says "8 left" and change it to what you wish the page to display.

For example: `<small class="spaces-left">Places Left: 8</small>`

Comment: Actually there is problem with me I'm unable to find class!!

Comment: If someone helps me to find class then it can be solved!!

Comment: @CodistanPro that div class is contained within: <html class="js" lang="en-US">